# How to configure cross-domain for GA4 manually with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I migrated my site to Google Analytics 4 and the cross-domain configuration is supposed to be easier and more automatic. I added the domains I want to configure in the admin but the URL parameter containing the gl_ in my domains is not created.

Both domains have the same measurement ID.

Reviewing the Google documentation it says that sometimes I have to set up the manual cross-domain but it only comes with the gtag and I am currently using Google Tag Manager.

How can I do this? Or if anyone knows what could be causing the conflict with my website?

Here are the two URLs:

First site: https://travelerswithcause.com/home
Second site: https://travelerswithcause.app/aplicar.aspx

The button that takes you to the second site is the one that says "Aplicar Ahora".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all seems that you have correctly configured the GA4 tag and the relevant linking between the domains is enabled for GA4 (see screenshot below).

[image]

Although you don't see GA4 cross-domain working because the needed _gl parameter is added to link elements (eg. an `<a href="xxx">aplicar</a>` element). Although your main button is not a link and GA4 doesn't identify the element as one to add the _gl parameter
[image]

Having that said, the way to make this work is to change the button to an actual link element and GA4 cross domain will work out of the box.

Comment: Now that you mention it that makes a lot of sense, thanks so much for noticing!